# AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'poll'

Tags: flask-socketio, eventlet

I'm running eventlet.monkey_patch() while trying to spin up a flask server which uses flask-socketio. This is the traceback:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/alhasan/MeetupPoint/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 777, in inner
    srv.serve_forever()
  File "/home/alhasan/MeetupPoint/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 612, in serve_forever
    HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 232, in serve_forever
    with _ServerSelector() as selector:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/selectors.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._poll = select.poll()
AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'poll'
```

I tried using monkey_patch, as previously I encountered the following error:

```
RuntimeError: You need to use the eventlet server. See the Deployment section of the documentation for more information.
```

I have eventlet installed.

```
...
eventlet==0.23.0
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
Flask-Script==2.0.6
Flask-SocketIO==3.0.1
...
```

Is there a fix for this?

My initial problem was that my server returns bad requests everytime I try to emit a message from the client. But, the other way works. Would really appreciate any kind of a solution. :)

Comment: Did you read `Deployment section of the documentation`?

Comment: Yes! Nevertheless, I found the solution. I wasn't doing the monkey_patch() early enough in my code. I'm not sure why, but doing the monkey_patch() at the earliest point in my code solved the issue.

Comment: Oh great. `gunicorn -k eventlet` would probably also call monkey_patch early enough. You may want to write your solution as answer below for other people.